# jQuery change font A to font B

Tags: jquery, fonts, font-awesome

I am using a safe web font for fast page loading.
I then want to switch this safe web font to a designer font after page load.

Something along the lines of:

```
if(font-family='FontA') -> this.css("font-family",'FontB');
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions for doing this in jquery.
'For each' loop perhaps?

Comment: What have you tried....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off defining and using a style:

```
.caseA {
  font-family: FontA;
}
.caseB {
  font-family: FontB;
}
```

Then flip between the two in js:

```
if ($object->hasClass('caseA')) {
  $object->removeClass('caseA');
  $object->addClass('caseB');
} else {
  $object->removeClass('caseB');
  $object->addClass('caseA');
}
```

But you can get away with using cascading styles and a single override:

```
.default {
  font-family: FontA;
}
.highlighted {
  font-family: FontB;
}
```

Then the js is clearer and easier to maintain:

```
if ($object->state === 'complete') {
  $object->removeClass('highlighted');
} else {
  $object->addClass('highlighted');
}
```